# CSS Как сделать секцию на весь экран с горизонтальным скроллом?

Tags: css, css3

Есть вот такой примитивный html/css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.main_section {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main_video {
  background-color: #ff0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="main_section">

  </div>
  <div class="main_video">

  </div>
</main>
```

Как сделать так, что б секция `main_section` занимала всю ширишу экрана, и сам этот объект `.main` мог скролиться по горизонтали, но что б вертикальных скроллов не добавлялось. Пробовал повторить хак с [вот этого примера](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/horizontal-scrolling-using-flexbox-f9d16817f742/). Но что-то пошло не так. Срабатывает если `.main_section {min-width:100vw;}` но меня не устраивает качество роботы, без скролла.

Comment: _"... мог скролиться по горизонтали, но что б вертикальных скроллов не добавлялось. ... меня не устраивает качество роботы, без скролла."_ Что-то Вы сами запутались и нас тоже запутать хотите :)

Comment: Все просто. Нужено адаптивное решение на весь экран первой секции. Что б сайт скролился по горизонтали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если  правильно понял ваш запрос, то вот:

```css
body {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 5000px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}

.main_section {
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
}

.main_video {
    background-color: #ff0;
    width: 5000px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<main class="main">
  <div class="main_section">

  </div>
  <div class="main_video">

  </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Ширину сделал, чтобы показать горизонтальный скролл

Comment: Это почти, то что мне надо. Меня интересует, что б данные секции были адаптивные по ширине и высоте устройств с которых их смотрят. Вы фиксируете определенными px значениями. Можно ли как-то с адаптивном варианте? Это важно

Comment: @BlackStar1991 высота - адаптивна, она настроена с помощью vh - единиц высоты. Так же есть единицы vw - единицы ширины. В своем примере я использовал пиксели для явного показа, что скролл в бок работает. А если вам нужен такой скролл, как на примере, то я бы лучше посоветовал взять слайдер из бутстрапа, там намного легче добавлять картинки и легче разобраться с адаптивностью под различные устройства